# Proving whether the sets are open or closed in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-verification

I've recently started studying topology and struggling with the concepts. I'd greatly appreciate if anyone can verify, as well as correct my proof, or concept should my proof be wrong.

Question: Prove whether the following sets are open or closed in $\mathbb{R}$

1){${G:={x \in \mathbb{R} | 0<x<1}}$}

Claim: the set is open

Proof: $x \in G$ iff $ x \in (0,1)$. Then, take $\epsilon = \frac{x-0}{2}$ for $x \leq 0.5$ and take $\epsilon = \frac{|x-1|}{2}$ for $x > 0.5$. Then, for any $x \in G$, $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \subset G$. Then, $ G $ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

2) Prove that any open interval $I:= (a,b)$ is open. Again, using the aforementioned proof, I can choose my epsilon to be the smaller of $\frac{x-a}{2}$ or $\frac{|x-b|}{2}$ and the claim follows.

3) $I=[0,1]$ is not open. There does not exist any $\epsilon>0$ such that for $0,1 \in I$, $V_{(\epsilon)} \subset I$. **I don't know if this is a valid proof. It sounds as if I'm stating something instead of actually proving it. Any leads?**

4) $I=[0,1]$ is closed. We have to prove that $\mathbb{R}-I = (-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$ is open. **Can anyone please help in proving this?**

Thank you.

Comment: Stylistically the use of $0.5$ would be better written as $\frac{1}{2}$ since decimal notation is atypical in proof based mathematics.

Comment: @CyclotomicField,  Useless quibble comparied to the glaring mistake of 1).

Comment: @WilliamElliot, can you please point out the apparent mistake made in 1)? Thank you.

Comment: @A.Asad.  A bracket is misplacec.

Comment: The right notation  for  the set in 1) is $G=\{x\in \Bbb R| 0<x<1\}.$ Computerese is not mathematical notation.   For 3) state that for any $e>0$ the set $(-e,e)=V_e(0) $ is not a subset of $[0,1]$ because $ (-e,0)$  is  a non-empty subset of $V_e(0)$  containing only negative numbers, which don't belong to $[0,1].$ For 4) use a similar method as in 1); For  $0\ne x\in \Bbb R,$ consider the set $\{y\in \Bbb R:  |y-x|<|x|\}. $ Note that I used a colon ($:$) instead of a vertical line ($|$), which I prefer; otherwise   the other vertical lines  (for the absolute values) make it hard to read.

Answer (score 2):

1) It's OK if you prove the inclusion $(x-\varepsilon , x+\varepsilon)\subset G$.

3) Simply note that $\forall \varepsilon>0$, $-\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\notin [0;1]$ but $-\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\in (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ thus $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)\not\subset [0;1]$. Similarly, $1+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{2}\in(1-\varepsilon , 1+\varepsilon)$ but not in $[0;1]$.

4) Prove that $(-\infty,0)$ and $(1;+\infty)$ are open as before and use the fact that a union of open sets is open.

Comment: How would I prove 1)? Also, for 3), do you mean that $\forall \epsilon>0$, the epsilon neighbourhood of 0 would never be a subset of $[0,1]$?

Comment: 1) Take $y$ s.t. $x-\varepsilon < y <x+\varepsilon$ and prove that $0<y<1$ using the value you chose for $\varepsilon$. 3) Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

For the fourth.

Let $(x_n) $ be a convergent sequence of elements in $[0,1] $.

$$\forall n \;\; 0\le x_n \le 1$$

$$\implies 0\le \lim_{+\infty}x_n\le 1$$

$$\implies \lim_{+\infty}x_n\in [0,1] $$

$$\implies [0,1] \text { is closed} .$$

This is not true for an open set.
Take $x_n=\frac {1}{n}\in (0,1) $

but $\lim_{+\infty}x_n=0\notin (0,1) $.

Comment: Thank you! This is through another result. I was hoping to go through definitions for proofs.

Answer (score 0):

3) Suppose its open and get to a contradiction by using the middle point.

4) Prove that $(-\infty, 0)$ is open and that $(0, \infty)$ is open so $R\setminus I$ is union of open sets hence $I$ is closed.

1) and 2) are ok.

Comment: What middle point, for 3? It's not open because of the endpoints, no?

Comment: Suppose an open interval (a, b) contains 0 and is subset of [0, 1], that can't be since (a, b) contains points to the left of 0, then think of the middle point between a and 0 and inequalities